# Swagger Schema self referencing when JToken is used in the model

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

My API model having one property which is of type JArray like

```
public class MyModel
{
   public JArray Credentials { get; set; }
   public string Property1 {get;set;}
}
```

For Credentials Swagger generating  like

```
"credentials": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/JToken"
            },
            "nullable": true
          }
```

and schema is like

```
 "JToken": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/JToken"
        }
      }
```

Here JToken is self-referencing, how can I avoid this self-referencing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While generating the Swagger document mapped the type of the JToken like below solved the self referencing problem

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
                c.MapType<JToken>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = typeof(JToken).Name });
            });
```

Comment: took me 3 hours to find this solution, the StackOverflow error was very generic to understand that JToken reference was the issue. Thank you so much